# why does a js function called inside componentDidMount occurring infinite time?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function which basically opens a url when a particular webpage is visited but whenever I call this function inside componentDidMount method, this url keeps on occurring continuously. why is it so and how can I avoid it?

I tried providing conditions using flag or setInterval function, but of no use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: launchExperimentForm = () => {
    const loc = this.props.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    if(loc === 'bali') {
      this.setState({
        isValidDestination: true
      });
      const launchExpForm = () => {
        
        this.props.history.push('/requested_trips/new');
       }